# How to create regular video chunks during recording?

Tags: python, opencv, video-capture, chunks, ip-camera

I want to create regular multiple video chunks when capturing the camera. Video chunks should be 3s with `.mp4` container. The capturing is fine but the chunks were not created.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import time
import os 

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

try:
    if not os.path.exists('chunks'):
        os.makedirs('chunks')
except OSError:
    print ('Error: Creating directory of data')
    
next_time = time.time() + 3

while True:
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = cap.read() 
    
    if time.time() > next_time:
        fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
        chunks = cv2.VideoWriter('/chunks/' + str(time.strftime('%d %m %Y - %H %M %S' )) + '.mp4', fourcc, 15, (640,480))
        next_time += 3

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few bugs in your code:

1. Nowhere in your loop did you call the `cv2.VideoWriter.write` method on your `chunks` objects. In your code it would look like this: `chunks.write(frame)`.
2. For every video you want to generate, you'll need to call the `cv2.VideoWriter.release` method, like this `chunks.release()`.
3. The duration of your resulting videos does not rely on the amount of time it takes to generate one; it relies on the number of frames written to the video and the framerate of the video. In your code you chose the framerate `15`, so every video would need 15 * 3 = 45 frames to be 3 seconds long.

Corrected your code might look something like this:

```
import os
import time
import cv2

try:
    if not os.path.exists('chunks'):
        os.makedirs('chunks')
except OSError:
    print('Error: Creating directory of data')

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*"XVID")
chunks = cv2.VideoWriter(f"chunks/{time.strftime('%d %m %Y - %H %M %S')}.mp4", fourcc, 15, (640, 480))
i = 0
while True:
    i += 1
    if i > 45:
        chunks.release()
        chunks = cv2.VideoWriter(f"chunks/{time.strftime('%d %m %Y - %H %M %S')}.mp4", fourcc, 15, (640, 480))
        i = 0
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    chunks.write(frame)

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Which works perfectly.